# How does SwingUtilies.invokeLater(new Runnable()) really work?

Tags: java, multithreading

As far as I know the method `SwingUtilies.invokeLater(new Runnable())` is used the force the EDT to do jobs that are defined in the `Runnable` - object , but how one can imagine this? Normally the `run()` method in the `Runnable`- object is used to execute Java stuff in a new Thread, but not here, because here the `Runnable`- object invokes only the EDT?

Comment: There is nothing magic about `Runnable` instances. They are just pieces of code to run in the future.  `SU.invokeLater` just adds the runnable itself to the event queue (in an event wrapper). At some point it reaches the head of the queue and the EDT's processing loop removes it for handling. To handle such an event, the EDT runs the runnable.

Comment: @Gene: You should add this as an answet, to get the credidts :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runnable is just an interface with single method run(). Anyone having access to a Runnable object can call this method. Threads do this. EDT does this. Executors do this. Your program can do so. This is just a convention. Other software can use different convention, say, ExecutorService can call Callable objects.

Internally, EDT has its own run method which, in a loop, extracts Runnable objects from its queue and calls their run() method.